# Final tails installation question

Tags: live-usb, tails-os

I'm following these instructions on how to boot Tails on my Mac using a USB: https://tails.boum.org/install/mac/usb/index.en.html

I've downloaded the intermediary Tails on to my USB and can successfully boot into Tails on my Mac. Part of the instructions (5/7) is to install the final Tails using Tails Installer. My question is why I must install the final Tails. If I can successfully boot into Tails on my USB with the intermediary Tails then what is the purpose of installing the final Tails?

Note- I'm not using Tails seriously. I'm trying to understand how the software works because it's interesting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the first USB was created in a non-tails operating system. It's an extra security measure.

Creating the final USB ensures that it won't be tainted with anything from the host OS you created the USB from.

**From the official site regarding MacOS install:**

> As it is currently impossible to install Tails directly from macOS,
>   this scenario requires creating an intermediary Tails on a second USB
>   stick. This intermediary Tails lacks important security and usability
>   features.

Comment: If I just use the USB with the intermediary Tails, am I able to do almost everything that the final Tails could do? I'm only looking to navigate around Tails for curiosity purposes anyway.

Comment: Tails doesn't make it clear what is missing on the intermediary USB. 
I would personally go through all the steps 

As a rule of thumb... even in testing/sandbox environments, always try to mimic production (real world) as much as possible which means go through the whole procedure even if just playing around.

Comment: Ahh okay that makes sense now. Thanks for the info!